# Convert Informatica Functions into Postgres

Tags: postgresql, informatica

I have a workflows in the Informatica which has Expression `RTRIM(LTRIM(EMP_NUM,'0'))`. This function I want to convert it in to the Postgres query. How can we do that ?

```
SELECT EMP_NUM, EMP_NAME, EMP_EMAIL FROM TEST.EMPLOYEE
```

Any pointers ?
Sample Data of EMP_NUM

```
01000
11
0000176
00090900088 
08009345353
```

Comment: What about `trim()`?

Comment: Can you show expression which removes spaces ?

Comment: Not clear whether you want to remove spaces or leading 0's  or both?

Comment: Hey As per RTRIM(LTRIM(EMP_NUM,'0')), I would need to remove leading zeros and then spaces before, after the number. HTH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To replicate what you show:

```
select rtrim(ltrim('001000 ', ' 0'));
 rtrim 
-------
 1000
(1 row)
```

String operators and functions for Postgres:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html

An alternate solution(converts to numeric):

```
select to_number('01000 ', '99999');
 to_number 
-----------
      1000
(1 row)
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html

```
to_number(text, text)   numeric     convert string to numeric   to_number('12,454.8-', '99G999D9S')
```